# ArrayList and HashSet memory allocation strange test results

Tags: java, scala, collections, performance-testing, scalameter

I was inspired by this topic: [Performance and Memory allocation comparision between List and Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799417/performance-and-memory-allocation-comparision-between-list-and-set) to actually run some tests and measure the performance difference between `ArrayList` and `HashSet`.

The most upvoted answer, in the mentioned topic, that intrigued me a lot ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799668/1549135)), says:

> HashSet consumes about 5.5 times more memory than ArrayList for the same number of elements

With the help of [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/) I wanted to make sure about this.

I made two, simple tests, adding from `10000` to `100000` elements to both `ArrayList` and `HashSet`. **Setting the initial size to the maximum did not change the results.** I tested those collections with two types:

- `Int` (putting consecutive numbers 0 to 100000)
- `String` (putting random String using Apache `RandomStringUtils`)

The code is available on my repository [here](https://github.com/atais/Performance-Tests/blob/master/src/test/scala/pl/msiatkowski/HashSetArrayListMemBenchmark.scala).

And running those, gave me this results:

- X-axis - size -> size of the collection
- Y-axis - value -> amount of kB used

For collections holding `Int`:
[image: Integer results]

For collections holding `String` of size 10:
[image: String results size 10]

For collections holding `String` of size 50:
[image: String results size 50]

**The question:**

What happened to the theory mentioned in the quoted answer? Is it false? Or probably there is some mistake on my side?

Thanks :)!

**Update after @andrzej answer** 
I have updated the code (and the repository) once again. The results are getting better but still the results are not 5.5x different. I am checking something more now.

Comment: How did you construct the elements? Did you guarantee that they are all different from each other?

Comment: @JFMeier please see the update (and also check the code on github :-) )

Comment: Your results look correct. 5.5 is the theoretical rate related to the overhead of the collection structure, it doesn't take into account object sizes. The larger the objects the lower this rate will be and your tests show that. Make your strings 50 characters long instead of 10 and the difference between array and set will be even smaller.

Comment: @AndrewLygin I have added chart for 50 char long Strings. It seems you are right, I will try to do some math and calculate the sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happened to the theory mentioned in the quoted answer? Is it false?

We can do some calculations to get an estimate:

Let's look at the OpenJDK source for [ArrayList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and [HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) (since `HashSet` is just a wrapper around `HashMap`) for hints.

Assume you have `n` elements to store.

### ArrayList

Elements are stored in the field `transient Object[] elementData;`. So length of `elementData` must be at least `n`.
Suppose you instantiated the list with `new ArrayList<>(n)` and so `elementData.length` is exactly `n`.
Then the size of your list is `n*c` bytes (where `c` is the size of an object reference). Here I ignored the `size` field and the [object header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header) of the list.

### HashMap

HashMap stores elements in `transient Node<K,V>[] table;` where a node has fields

```
final int hash;
final K key;
V value;
Node<K,V> next;
```

Then for storing `n` elements you need `n` nodes or `n*(3*c + 4)` bytes i.e each node has 3 object references - `3*c` bytes - and an `int` - 4 bytes.
According to [HashMap javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

Based on this I'll estimate that `table.length == 2*n`.
Summing up a hashmap requires `n*2*c + n*(3*c + 4) = n*5*c + n*4` bytes.

### Summary

Now let's suppose you have a 64bit JVM and the size of an object reference is 8 bytes (i.e `c = 8`) (let's igntore things like [compressed oops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)).
Then `n*5*c + n*4 = n*5*8 + n*4 = n*44` and `n*c = n*8`.
Finally `n*44 / n*8 = 5.5`

So the original theory that `HashSet` consumes about 5.5 times more memory than `ArrayList` seems quite plausible and it seems likely that something is not right with your measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Please add measurement object as return value.

```
measure method "Int" in {
  using(sizes) curve listS in { i =>
    val c = new util.ArrayList[Int](i)
    (0 until i).map(t => c.add(t))
    c // return c
  }

  using(sizes) curve setS in { i =>
    val c = new util.HashSet[Int]()
    (0 until i).map(t => c.add(t))
    c // return c
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, there're two problems here:

1. As Andrzej mentioned, you don't return your collections from the benchmark snippets. Scalameter measures footprint by performing GC before and after the benchmark execution (find details [here](https://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.7/executors/)). If you don't return the collection, it's just removed from memory by the after-test GC and test results are useless. It explains why the memory footprints in your tests remain small (around four bytes per object) and don't differ. But it doesn't explain why the footprint grows when the collection size grows, and here comes the second problem.
2. Some garbage collectors (CMS and G1 particularly) don't guarantee that after performing a garbage collection all the dead objects are removed from memory. If your JVM choses one of these collectors (or if you specify it manually), that would explain the memory footprint uptrend. You can check what collector is in use by providing `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option to your test and finding the values of `UseG1GC` and `UseConcMarkSweepGC` flags.

Comment: Before the last line was `(0 until i).map(t => c.add(t))` - it was Seq[Boolean] of size i

Comment: That confirms the first problem and explains those "four bytes per object". That Seq[Boolean] is used to calculate the footprint instead of the real collection that is removed by GC right before the final memory measurement. Just return the real collections from your snippets and you'll see the difference.