# How to combine two list string into one list

Tags: java, list, collections

I have two list string different,

```
List<String> A= [1,2,3,4]; 
List<String> B= [1,2,5,6];
```

And I want to combine two list, in new list string in 
    List C = new Arraylist ();

how to combine two list string , be like the example:

```
    C = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Comment: A.addAll(B) will add all B elements to A

Comment: Use a Set implementation for merge without duplication

Comment: If you got the answer then accept that and if you are still not found desire answer then please paste your problem including exception if it is.

Comment: How to reach this result: C = [1,2] - only unique items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Collection.addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29), and a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), to remove duplicates and keep the result sorted.

```
Set<String> c = new TreeSet<String>(a); //create a Set with all the elements in a
c.addAll(b); //add all the elements in b
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get them combined

```
combined = new ArrayList<String>();
combined.addAll(A);
combined.addAll(B);
```

This will get the uniques

```
List<String> uniques = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(combined));
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this :

```
listOne.removeAll(listTwo);
listTwo.addAll(listOne);
Collections.sort(listTwo);
```

You can remove the third line if you do not want it to be sorted.

Comment: this is better but only if original lists can be modified.

Comment: If you want the first list not to be modified then you can store it in a temporary list.A very common coding scheme:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to merge the results of both lists: using `List#addAll` or `Set#addAll`. The main difference between both is heavily explained here: [What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035008/1065197)

Based on your request, you should merge both lists without repeating the items using a `Set`

```
List<String> lstA = new ArrayList<String>();
lstA.add("1");
lstA.add("2");
lstA.add("3");
lstA.add("4");
List<String> lstB = new ArrayList<String>();
lstA.add("1");
lstA.add("2");
lstA.add("5");
lstA.add("6");
Set<String> lstC = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
lstC.addAll(A);
lstC.addAll(B);
List<String> lstAB = new ArrayList(lstC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of A and B seems to be wrong.

However, given two lists A and B, to combine them into C, you can use the following code:
C.addAll(A);
C.addAll(B);

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> A= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> B= new ArrayList<String>();

Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(A);
set.addAll(B);
System.out.println(new ArrayList<String>(set));
```

Comment: `TreeSet` maintains the data sorted, not ordered. `LinkedHashSet` maintains the data ordered but not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(A); // for keeping the output sorted else you can also use java.util.HashSet
  set.addAll(B);
  List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `List<String>` in sorted order, use this piece of code

```
    String a[] = {"1","2","3","4"};
    String b[] = {"1","2","5","6"};
    List<String> A= Arrays.asList(a); 
    List<String> B= Arrays.asList(b); 

    Set<String> CTemp = new TreeSet<>();  
    CTemp.addAll(A);
    CTemp.addAll(B);

    List<String> C = new ArrayList<>(CTemp);
```