# `HashSet` only contains unique element? what is the best scenario to use `HashSet` instead of `List`. Both have approximately same function

Tags: list, generics, hashset

`HashSet` only contains unique element? what is the best scenario to use `HashSet` instead of `List`. Both have approximately same function.

Comment: No, they're very different. Do you want an ordered list of values which can include duplicates? Use `List<T>`. Do you want an unordered *set* of values (so no duplicates)? Use `HashSet<T>`...

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985029/hashset-vs-arraylist

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use