# Why set <Integer> is sorting added values?

Tags: java, set, java-collections-api

When I start to add value into `Set<Integer>` I get sorting elements.
Please refer to this example:

```
Set<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();
generated.add(2);
generated.add(1);
generated.add(0);
```

Here I get sorting `Set` `[0, 1, 2]`. I would like to get value as I add to `generated` object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is this HashSet producing sorted output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648521/how-is-this-hashset-producing-sorted-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashSet` does not have a predictable order for elements. Use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to preserve insertion order of elements in a set:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.

```
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
generated.add(2);
generated.add(1);
generated.add(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it's just a co-incidence that you get sorted value first time. If you run that code multiple time, you'll see the output in some random order. That's because a `HashSet` doesn't enforce any ordering on elements you add.

Now to get the elements in the order you inserted, you can use `LinkedHashSet`, that maintains the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

The `HashSet` does not guarantee the order of the elements. From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So, in order to keep guarantee the order a `LinkedHashSet` can be used. From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.
>
> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).

Simply instantiate your `Set` like this:

```
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, regarding the title of your question, `Set<Integer>` is only the declaration type and its not responsible of any sorting / unsorting behavior, the main reason for using the `Set` interface is when caring about uniqueness — it doesn't allow duplicates, additional informations from [Javadocs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements.

**Second,** it's pure concidence that you got sorted set, use `HashSet` when you don't care about order when iterating through it, more infos from [javadocs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time. This class permits the null element.

**Third**, regarding what you are looking for:

> I would like to get value as I add to generated object.

then you need to use `LinkedHashSet` which takes care of the order in which elements were inserted, again from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in
>   which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that
>   insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the
>   set

you may use it simply like this:

```
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```

**Fourth and Last**, as additional information, another important collection that you need to be aware of it, is the `TreeSet`which guarantees that the elements will be sorted in ascending order, according to natural order, [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used