# how sorting works in a java set

Tags: java, sorting, set, java-stream

using this method I created, I don't understand why it returns me a list of integers already in order when on the java doc the set shouldn't order the elements without me telling it.

*what this method do*: the method given a list of strings as input, returns the set of lengths of the strings in the list

```
public static Set<Integer> test(List<String> inputList){
    return inputList.stream()
        .map(String::length)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

doing this on the main

```
List<String> p2 = List.of("aaaa", "aa", "aaa", "a");
Set<Integer> r2 = test(p2);
System.out.println(r2);
```

it returns this list : `[1, 2, 3, 4]` when I would have expected `[4, 2, 3, 1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is this HashSet producing sorted output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648521/how-is-this-hashset-producing-sorted-output)

Comment: If you add a `System.out.println(r2.getClass());` you'll see that you are getting a HashSet. Why that appears sorted for small ints, see linked question. Add a bunch of long strings and the order will disappear.

Comment: To summarize linked question - this is only a coincidence, because integers hash to themselves. To see different ordering, collect like this  (for example) - `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>(3, 3)));`, prints `[4, 1, 2, 3]` on my machine.

Comment: Coming soon to a JDK near you: [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)

Answer (score 2):

`Set`s generally don't have any order you can rely on.

The purpose of a `Set` is to have a collection of elements that does not allow duplicates without considering the order of the elements. You can essentially add, remove elements and check whether an element is present.

If you want a data structure that is indexed, you should probably use a `List`.
Lists are indexed and have an order.

```java
public static List<Integer> test(List<String> inputList){
    return inputList.stream()
        .map(String::length)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, there are specific `Set` implementations that gurantee a specific order.

For example, if you want a `Set` that just preserves order, you might want to consider using a `LinkedHashSet` which is essentially a `HashSet` that keeps insertion order:

```java
public static Set<Integer> test(List<String> inputList){
    return inputList.stream()
        .map(String::length)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

If you want the set to be sorted in some way, you can also uses a sorted set implementation like `TreeSet`:

```java
public static Set<Integer> test(List<String> inputList){
    return inputList.stream()
        .map(String::length)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(()->new TreeSet<>(Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed())));
}
```

In the above code, `Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed()` creates a `Comparator` which is used for configuring the order of elements the `Set` should be sorted in. `Comparator.naturalOrder()` refers to a `Comparator` which compares by the "natural order" of the elements which is ascending for `Integer`s. `reversed()` is then used for reversing the order (descending `Integer`s).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your set is in sorted order is purely coincidental and based on the `hash values`, the `capacity` of the set, and the `load factor`.  All of those are mentioned in the JavaDoc for [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(int,float)) but explained in more detail [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html).

Consider the following:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set);
```

Prints

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Now adjust the size and load capacity to force a different behavior.

```
set = new HashSet<>(1,10f);
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set);
```

prints

```
[12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

And if you want to preserve the insertion order use a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#LinkedHashSet())

```
set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set);
```

prints

```
[13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The bottom line is that except for some special implementations including [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) which wasn't discussed above, `Sets` are inherently unordered and any appearance that they are is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

The Answers [by dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76975774/642706) and [by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76977006/642706) are both correct and smart. I'll modify the code seen in the first to take advantage of new features in Java.

## tl;dr

Use the new `SequencedCollection` interface in Java 21+.

```java
public SequencedCollection < Integer > calculateStringLengths ( final List < String > inputList )
{
    return inputList
            .stream ( )
            .map ( ( String s ) -> Math.toIntExact ( s.codePoints ( ).count ( ) ) )  // Calculate the true count of characters in this string.
            .toList ( );
}
```

## Sequenced collections in Java 21+

[Java 21](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/21/) brings some new interfaces and methods to the venerable Java Collections framework. The new features recognize the concept of *sequenced collections*.

[image: diagram of three new interfaces added to Java 21]

For more info, see [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431). And see the video by [José Paumard](https://fr.linkedin.com/in/jos%C3%A9-paumard-2458ba5) on the *JEP Café* channel on YouTube. See [early-access Javadoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/).

Let's modify the code shown in the [Answer by dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76975774/642706) to use the new Java 21 features.

Start with this piece:

```java
public static Set<Integer> test(List<String> inputList){
    return inputList.stream()
        .map(String::length)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Notice that this method must return either:

- The overly general [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) interface, with no indication of this collection promising to be in a certain order.
- The overly specific [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class, which remembers insertion order.

Java offers the `SortedSet` interface, and its successor [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html). These are meant for collections with a *sorted* order. But [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) with its *insertion* order cannot implement those interfaces.

So, voilà, Java 21 adds the [`SequencedSet`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) interface, to represent `LinkedHashSet` as well as `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet` implementations such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Let's pop that into the code snippet from above. And do some reformatting and renaming.

```java
public SequencedSet < Integer > calculateStringLengths ( List < String > inputList )
{
    return inputList
            .stream ( )
            .map ( String :: length )
            .collect (
                    Collectors.toCollection ( LinkedHashSet :: new )
            );
}
```

And we could make that the more general `SequencedCollection`.

```java
public SequencedCollection < Integer > calculateStringLengths ( List < String > inputList )
{
    return inputList
            .stream ( )
            .map ( String :: length )
            .collect (
                    Collectors.toCollection ( LinkedHashSet :: new )
            );
}
```

Le's try it.

```java
List < String > listOfStrings = List.of ( "aaaa" , "aa" , "aaa" , "a" );
SequencedCollection < Integer > stringLengths = this.calculateStringLengths ( listOfStrings );
System.out.println ( "stringLengths = " + stringLengths );
```

When run:

> stringLengths = [4, 2, 3, 1]

### `Set` forbids duplicates

But multiple input strings could very well have the same length. And `Set` implementations cannot allow duplicates. So really, we should be outputting a `List` rather than a `Set`.

Fortunately, no need to change the signature of our `calculateStringLengths` method — `List` & `ArrayList` implement `SequencedCollection`. So we can swap:

```java
            .collect (
                    Collectors.toCollection ( LinkedHashSet :: new )
            );
```

… with:

```java
            .toList() ;
```

… like this:

```java
public SequencedCollection < Integer > calculateStringLengths ( List < String > inputList )
{
    return inputList
            .stream ( )
            .map ( String :: length )
            .toList() ;
}
```

We get the same results.

> stringLengths = [4, 2, 3, 1]

### Use code points, not `char`

Unfortunately, you used the `String#length` method which is essentially broken. Add a character such as  to your input strings to see incorrect results.

That `length` method uses the `char` type. As a 16-bit value, that `char` type is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead of `char` use [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

Replace `String :: length` with `s.codePoints ( ).count ( )`. But that call returns a `long`, so we must either change `< Integer >` to `< Long >` or we must cast the `long` to an `int` since a string’s length cannot be more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. For defensive programming, we can be extra safe by using `Math.toIntExact` instead of a direct cast, as this method throws an exception in case of integer overflow.

```java
public SequencedCollection < Integer > calculateStringLengths ( final List < String > inputList )
{
    return inputList
            .stream ( )
            .map ( ( String s ) -> Math.toIntExact ( s.codePoints ( ).count ( ) ) )  // Calculate the true count of characters in this string.
            .toList ( );
}
```

Let's try this final version of our code. We add  as a test of our more accurate string-length calculation.

```java
List < String > listOfStrings = List.of ( "aaaa" , "aa" , "aaa" , "a" , "" );
SequencedCollection < Integer > stringLengths = this.calculateStringLengths ( listOfStrings );
System.out.println ( "stringLengths = " + stringLengths );
```

> stringLengths = [4, 2, 3, 1, 1]