# What does List<Set<Integer>> mean?

Tags: java, list, set

One of the questions I have been given asks:

> All the lines should be stored in an object of
>   type `List<Set<Integer>>`.

How do you write this in Java, as in how do you initialise this list? I've never seen this before.

Please provide a link to an explanation as i'm not sure what this is called in Java so have no idea about how to learn about it. Thank You.

Comment: I've edited the question for you, but in the future, you can use backticks ( ` ) to specify code snippets, so that angle brackets work.

Comment: It's using [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) The given is a list of sets that are collections of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a **List** of **Set**s where each **Set** can hold only **Integer**s.

```
Set<Integer> singlesSet = new HashSet<>();
singlesSet.add(1);
singlesSet.add(2);

Set<Integer> tensSet = new HashSet<>();
tensSet.add(10);
tensSet.add(20);

List<Set<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(singlesSet);
list.add(tensSet);

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Note that in Java 7 and above you can use the "diamond operator" in the `new` statements: `new HashSet<>()` and `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: that is the very same as my example, and you get +4 and I only +1 :(. And I was quicker :/

Comment: SO is a harsh master, @martijnn2008! :-P I'd +1'd Jerome because I just looked at the "answered" timestamp, not noticing the history/edit timestamps. So I just +1'd you, since you had the full answer first. But the diamond operator holds for your code, too. :)

Comment: I don't think diamond operator is the way to go for beginners. But still you have a good point. ty btw :)

Answer (score 3):

Example of usages of `Set` and `List`. Note that elements in a `TreeSet` are always sorted.

```
List<Set<Integer>> listofsets = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
Set<Integer> set1 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
set1.add(1);
set1.add(2);

Set<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
set2.add(6);
set2.add(4);

listofsets.add(set);

// listofsets = {{1,2}, {4,6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `List` interface represents an abstract list of *things*. Any class the implements `List` (for example, `LinkedList`) must implement its methods and behave according to its contract.

You can essentially think of it as an array, but keep in mind that arrays are only one kind of list, and that implementations of `List` do no **have** to use arrays internally.

The `Set` also represents a collection of elements, but with no relationship or connection between them. Visually, you can think of a set as a sort of bag of *things*. You can add and remove things from the bag, but none of the items **need** to be related.

An `Integer`, of course, is just an object wrapper around Java's `int` primitive.

As such, a `List<Set<Integer>>` object would be *similar* to a two-dimensional array, only without a defined order in the second dimension.

You would initialize a `List<Set<Integer>>` as follows:

```
    List<Set<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

Where `ArrayList` and `HashSet` can be any classes that implement `List` and `Set`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Like this `List<Set<Integer>> yourList = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();`?

You may want to take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

The short way:

```
    List<Set<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    list.add(set);
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
   ....
```

[What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035008/4296831)