# difference between ArrayList contains() method and set duplicate filteration

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the difference between `ArrayList` `contains()` method and set duplicate filtration and the advantages of using that?

Comment: You should take a class on data structures and algorithms

Comment: ArrayList.contains() method returns true if the object is contained in ArrayList. Can you please elaborate on _set duplicate filteration_ ?

Comment: While  inserting values in set It will not allow duplicates. But we can achieve the same functionality in arrayList by using contains method. So why we need to use set for unique elements.Please explain if there is any advantages by using set (in terms of performance etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Set`, it ensures it cannot contain duplicate elements based on `equals`. Using a `List`, it does not do that automatically. You would have to use

```
if(!list.contains(element)){
    list.add(element);
}
```

see also [What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list)

As for performance, it depends on your usage pattern. It depends on which operations you do frequently. Anyway, if you don't have any special requirements which make it really necessary to optimize performance, use a `Set` since it makes your intention clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I want to know is there any performance advantages if we use Set instead of ArrayList contains() method while adding elements. What is the best practice and why?

Answer (score 0):

Set guarantees no duplicates. If you want to have a Collection that has no duplicates, using a Set means that you do not need to do duplicate elimination yourself. So you need to write, test and debug less code. That makes you more productive. You replace code you might write with code in the Set implementation. As the writers of that code are probably far better programmers than you, that code will be more efficient and less buggy than code you could write. The HashSet implementation in particular does past insertions. Anyone reading your code (including a future you) that has a Set, rather than a Collection or List, can instantly see that the collection does not have duplicates.  It makes your code partly and reliably document itself.