# Storing null values inside ArrayList and Set

Tags: arraylist, set

```
class Employee
{
  int id;

  Employee(int id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getID()
  {   
    return id;
  }

  public void displayID()
  {
    System.out.println("ID="+id);
  }
}

public class Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Employee employee1 = new Employee(100);
    Employee employee3 = null;

    List<Employee> arrayListEx = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Set<Employee> setEx = new HashSet<Employee>();

    arrayListEx.add(employee1);
    arrayListEx.add(employee3);
    setEx.add(employee1);
    setEx.add(employee3);

  }
}
```

Friends,
As per my understanding Set should not allow null values to get added to it. 
Should the above code snippet throw compile time error for "setEx.add(employee3)" ?
Please advice, Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you compile it and see ? there are online compilers in case you don't want to install one

Comment: I did that unfortunatley. In Runtime I got NullPointer but no compile time error. Then I thought of asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Hashset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) documentation: "This class permits the null element". The file will compile.

You mentioned you believe that `Set` doesn't allow nulls. This depends on its implementation ([link to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html))

Comment: Thanks Chakeda, This definately helps. If HashSet allows null values I am wondering what is the difference between an ArrayList & HashSet.

Sorry if it seems like a basic question ....

Comment: @Jagann you probably want to see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list