# Java: Best way to remove duplicated list in a list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

I have a list of list:

```
List<List<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

What would be the best way to remove the duplicated list in myList?

For example, in the following list of list:

```
[[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

I would like to reduce it to:

```
[[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Convert `List<List<T>>` to `Set<List<T>>`

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(myList))`.

Comment: `myList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to copy it into an order-preserving set (or, more generally, any kind of set, if you don't care about the ordering), and then back into the list:

```
myList = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(myList));
```

Comment: I cant tell you how much this solution has helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set instead of a list. Sets do not allow duplicates. [What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list)