# algorithm for removing common elements from different lists in the program below

Tags: java, algorithm, list, arraylist, collections

This is the code for evaluating factors of given integer array. The problem is I need to find LCM from the list I have received as output. Suggest something for removing duplicate elements from list

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] ar = {6,12,36};
        for (int a:
             ar) {
            System.out.println(getFactor(a));
        }
```

**getFactor(long) returns the list of factors**

```
private static List<Integer> getFactor(long n) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=2;n!=1;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                l.add(i);
                n=n/i;
                i=1;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

/*Input
6,12,36
Output
[2, 3]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 3]*/
```

**Problem**
remove the [2,3] duplicates from other lists to get LCM(Least Common Multiple).

Comment: Well seeing as you are removing elements to get LCM why not calculate LCM directly from given input? `LCM(a,b) = a*b/GCD(a,b)` and GCD can easilly be found with Euclid algorithm, Java even has GCD implementation in it's BigInteger library `BigInteger.valueOf(a).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).intValue()`

Comment: You arrays are sorted. You can use it to eliminate duplicates with simple for loops

Answer (score 1):

No where in your code you're calculating the lcm.
All I see is you have found the factors of three numbers.

```
[2, 3]   -> Factors of 6
[2, 2, 3] -> Factors of 12
[2, 2, 3, 3] -> -> Factors of 6
```

You'll have to write another function to calculate the lcm.

Comment: I know the recursive approach for gcd(x,y) and after that we evaluate lcm. I was just wondering if we can find lcm by evaluating the factors and eliminating the common ones

Answer (score 1):

> Suggest something for removing duplicate elements from list

Use `Set` instead of a `List`

```
private static Set<Integer> getFactor(long n) {
    Set<Integer> l = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 2; n != 1; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            l.add(i);
            n = n / i;
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

Recommended reading: [What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it didn't work in my case so what I did was picking the shortest length then multiply all the elements till it exists in other lists, and that worked for me.