# Using and printing content of Set<Set<T>> in Java

Tags: java, set

I have a Java file with this variable, and there should be String content in it:

`private Set<Set<MyAxiom>> explanations;`

I read that Sets are collections of some type of data (which should be `MyAxiom`, I guess), but couldn't find how to access them, and I need to stamp.

I tried to retrieve these explanations with a get-return method

```
public Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> getExpl(int index) {
    return this.explanations(index);
}
```

Similar methods worked out for other normal variables, but I think a `Set` needs is own commands, doesn't it? And by the way this is a set of sets. I find it really complex. I would be really glad to know how to handle them, and if not, a documentation link would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Maybe adding this is useful for your answers. That explanations variable is in a javabean used by a jsp file. It's within a webapp project I compile with maven. The compilation is fine with this code below, but when I access via browser (with Tomcat) I get the error `The method getExpl() in the type BundleQueryManagement is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

This is the alternate method I tried:

```
public Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> getExpl() {
    return this.explanations;
}
```

Or even

```
public void getExpl() {
    return this.explanations;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a `Set<MyAxiom>` returned, or `Axiom` ?

Comment: As far as I can see, your method is only valid, if you `return this.explanation;`

Comment: [The documentation for `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: Do you mean this.explanationS? I tried this too with
----
public Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> getExpl() {
    return this.explanations;
}

But an error occurs.
This java class is a javabean used in a jsp page. I use Maven for the compilation and it works fine, but when I try to launch the jsp page i get an error saying "The method getExpl() in the type BundleQueryManagement is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Answer (score 2):

Your code tells that you have an index value and you want to access corresponding value in your `Set`. But actually you cannot access `Set` using index as `Set`s are unordered collections of objects. So it's not possible.

If you want to access your elements this way, then you should consider using a list instead.

See also: [Why doesn't java.util.Set have get(int index)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/769731/2815219)

---

**EDIT**

You can print all elements recursively like this:

```
public void printExpl(Set<Set<MyAxiom>> explanations) {
    for (Set <MyAxiom> exp: explanations) {
        for (MyAxiom obj: exp) {
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to print out the whole group of elements, which should be String elements

Comment: @GondraKkal see the edited part of answer. This will print all the elements. Make sure to override `toString()` method appropriately.

Comment: Wait I need to return said elements, so I can print them in a jsp file that will use this method. How does it change? Also, what are exp and obj? I would like to understand more what you did here

Comment: @GondraKkal `exp` and `obj` are just variable names. I'm printing individual elements. If you want, then you can return them as per your requirements.

Comment: Ok so I will have to modify it in this way:
public void printExpl(Set<Set<MyAxiom>> explanations) {
    for (Set <MyAxiom> exp: explanations) {
        for (MyAxiom obj: exp) {
            return obj.toString();
        }
    }
}

Comment: Ok so I will have to modify it in this way:
public void printExpl(Set<Set<MyAxiom>> explanations) {
    for (Set <MyAxiom> exp: explanations) {
        for (MyAxiom obj: exp) {
            return obj.toString();
        }
    }
}

EDIT: @Raman Sahasi  now that I think about it, I cannot have multiple returns, so how can I group all my variables in an unique one?

Comment: Tried your code, but this occurred:
[ERROR] /.../myProgram.java:[lineOfTheError] incompatible types: unexpected return value

Comment: @GondraKkal I'm just printing value in my method, that's why I've given return type `void`. If you want a value in return type, then it's obvious that you should change the return type appropriately.

Comment: Even putting 'void' return me an error, that what I meant. How can I modify the code with no stamp and returning the value in explanations instead?