# Make string manipulation more convenient in Mathematica

Tags: string, wolfram-mathematica

With Mathematica I always feel that strings are "second class citizens."  Compared to a language such as PERL, one must juggle a lot of code to accomplish the same task.

The available functionality is not bad, but the syntax is uncomfortable.  While there are a few shorthand forms such as `<>` for `StringJoin` and `~~` for `StringExpression`, most of the string functionality lacks such syntax, and uses clumsy names like: `StringReplace`, `StringDrop`, `StringReverse`, `Characters`, `CharacterRange`, `FromCharacterCode`, and `RegularExpression`.

In Mathematica strings are handled like mathematical objects, allowing `5 "a" + "b"` where `"a"` and `"b"` act as symbols.  This is a feature that I would not change, even if that would not break stacks of code.  Nevertheless it precludes certain terse string syntax, wherein the expression `5 "a" + "b"` would be rendered `"aaaaab"` for example.

---

#### What is the best way to make string manipulation more convenient in Mathematica?

Ideas that come to mind, either alone or in combination, are:

1. Overload existing functions to work on strings, e.g. `Take`, `Replace`, `Reverse`.

   - This was the original topic of my question to which Sasha replied.  It was seen as inadvisable.
2. Use shortened names for string functions, e.g. `StringReplace` >> `StrRpl`, `Characters` >> `Chrs`, `RegularExpression` >> "RegEx"
3. Create new infix syntax for string functions, and possibly new string operations.
4. Create a new container for strings, e.g. `str["string"]`, and then definitions for various functions.  (This was suggested by Leonid Shifrin.)
5. A variable of (4), expand strings (automatically?) to characters, e.g. `"string"` >> `str["s","t","r","i","n","g"]` so that the characters can be seen by `Part`, `Take`, etc.
6. Call another language such as PERL from within Mathematica to handle string processing.
7. Create new string functions that conglomerate frequently used sequences of operations.

Comment: There's a few shorter names for string manipulation in [dreeves](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4234/dreeves) contribution to the [Mma tool bag question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4213366#4213366). I'm not sure if overloading is a good idea...

Comment: I think Simon is right. Having a list of lists of strings and applying Map[... ,Infinity] to those functions will bring up a debugging nightmare

Comment: @Simon @belisarius off-topic, is there an apparent reason why I was down-voted for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683228 ?

Comment: @Mr. fixed that :). It's a common behavior of X language bigots when they see an out-of-their-yogurt-flask answer

Comment: I also think that overloading is not a good idea. You may not only break your code (which you can debug), but also break some top-level built-in (or third-party, if you use other add-ons) code, may be even without knowing it. If I really had to overload list functions, I'd construct a type (container) with the custom head (say `string`, so the string "abc" would be converted into `string["abc"]`), and overload list functions of interest only on that type via UpValues (like `string/:Take[s_string,k_]:= Map[StringTake[#,k]&,s]`). This is much safer.

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason these operations have String* names is that they have tiny differences compared to their list counterparts. Specifically compare [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) to [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringCases.html).

Now the way to to achieve what you want is to do it like this:

```
Begin["StringOverload`"];
{Drop, Cases, Take, Reverse};
Unprotect[String];
ToStringHead[Drop] = StringDrop;
ToStringHead[Take] = StringTake;
ToStringHead[Cases] = StringCases;
ToStringHead[Reverse] = StringReverse;
String /: 
 HoldPattern[(h : Drop | Cases | Take | Reverse)[s_String, rest__]] :=
  With[{head = ToStringHead[h]}, head[s, rest]]
RemoveOverloading[] := 
 UpValues[String] = 
  DeleteCases[UpValues[String], 
   x_ /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated[x], (Drop | Cases | Take | Reverse)]]
End[];
```

You get to load stuff with `Get` or `Need`, and remove the overloading with `RemoveOverloading[]` called with the correct context.

```
In[21]:= Cases["this is a sentence", RegularExpression["\\s\\w\\w\\s"]]

Out[21]= {" is "}

In[22]:= Take["This is dangerous", -9]

Out[22]= "dangerous"

In[23]:= Drop["This is dangerous", -9]

Out[23]= "This is "
```

I do not think doing this is the right way to go, though. You might consider introducing shorter symbols in some context which would automatically evaluate to `String*` symbols