# Randomly select an item from a list

Tags: java, random, collections

How can I randomly select an item from a list in Java?
e.g. I have

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");
```

etc.... How can I randomly select from this list using the

```
Random myRandomizer = new Random();
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort and duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set

Comment: @gh, your reference for duplicate is incorrect as you linked to randomly selecting from sets, not lists :)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Random randomizer = new Random();
String random = list.get(randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));
```

Comment: @Hamidreza well, in the OP's example, it would be `myRandomizer`. The `nextInt()` call should have made that obvious.

Comment: This returns the first element of the list for me, every single time.

Answer (score 19):

Clean Code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");
String random = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

Simple and generic solution, for retrieving random element from your collections:

```
public static <T> T getRandomListElement(List<T> items) {
    return items.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(items.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding in Kotlin the simplest way is writing:

```
val randomElement = listName.shuffled()[0]
```

or

```
val randomElement = listName.random()
```

I hope it'll help you :)

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, you can use

```
random()
```

defined in kotlin.collections

For example,
Assuming

```
val results = ArrayList<Result>() //Get the list from server or add something to the list
val myRandomItem = results.random()
```