# Select Randomly an object from a list (Image)

Tags: java, image, random, jlabel

guys I was wondering if it was a way to put a list of for example JLabels, and with a method select randomly one of them.

And if the JLabels are the images it will still work??

Thanks for all your answers;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomly select an item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487592/randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picking a random element from a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
Random r = new Random();
        List<JLabel> yourList; //populate your list beforehand. yourList.add(JLabel blah); and so on
        JLabel randomJLabel = yourList.get(r.nextInt(yourList.size()));
```