# Java Random Object

Tags: java, object

I created a few objects in main class and bounded with NPC class.

```
NPC zagolar = new NPC("Zagolar",25000,25000,250,50);
NPC riginmon = new NPC("Riginmon",50000,50000,500,100);
NPC setkov = new NPC("Schetkov",100000,100000,1000,150);
NPC tortugate = new NPC("Tortugate",200000,200000,2000,200);
NPC echonia = new NPC("Echonia",225000,225000,2500,400);
NPC cajsa = new NPC("Cajsa",250000,250000,2750,500);
NPC vaula = new NPC("Vaula",300000,300000,3500,700);
```

I want to choose currentNPC from one of them randomly. Can you help me about it?

Comment: Add them to an array or a list and then pick a random index.

Comment: A very concise answer, add all of them to a list and then use `NPC randomItem = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))`

Comment: Thank you so much, question might be simple but I'm the new one in programming.

Comment: In other words, use the solution from [this answer: Randomly select an item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487592/randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Depending on taste, may instead use an array and a solution from [this answer: How to randomly pick an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array). It will work for an array of `NPC` objects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array, because its probably faster than an ArrayList and it does not convert everything to Objects. So, initialize an array like that :

```
NPC[] random_npc=new NPC[] {zagolar,riginmon,setkov,tortugate,echonia,cajsa,vaula};
```

and then pick a random element :

```
NPC choosed_npc=random_npc[(int)(Math.random()*random_npc.length)];
```

(Math.random gives a number bigger than 0 and smaller than 1)

Comment: Rather than `7` I would definitely use `random_npc.length`. It’s both easier to understand and less prone to get erroneous next time you change the code. Otherwise nice!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.