# Retrieve random object from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The method below is the method I am using to populate my array. However I wish to return a random `deals_information`object from my ArrayList of type `Deals_Information` but am not quite sure how.

```
    public void populateArray() {

    databaseReference.child("FruitDeals").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            final ArrayList<Deals_Information> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                Deals_Information deals_information = child.getValue(Deals_Information.class);
                myArray.add(deals_information);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: java.lang.Random is your friend....as one could have probably found out by typing java + random into google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving a random item from ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomly select an item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487592/randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: @moondaisy That's a bad one to link in my opinion because the actual answer is hidden in a comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Random to get a random int from the range of 0 and the size-1 of your collection.

Since Java 1.7, the recommended Random implementation is ThreadLocalRandom.

```
private int randomInt(final int from, final int to) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(from, to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ArrayLists have a `get()` function, the way to do this is to first generate a random number by using the `math.random()` function, and then use the `get()` function of your ArrayList to call the object at that randomly generated index.