# Pick random strings and print them out

Tags: java

I want to have a bunch of strings written out and print them out randomly in Java. So something like:

```
string x = ksdhksh
string y = hjkhkj
string p = ugdajkghs
string w = kdhahj

System.out.print "Game Over" + random var picked by code
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomly select an item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487592/randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String x = "ksdhksh";
    String y = "hjkhkj";
    String p = "ugdajkghs";
    String w = "kdhahj";
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(x,y,p,w);
    System.out.print("Game Over " + myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size())));
```