# random.choice from set?

Tags: python, list, random, set

I'm working on an AI portion of a guessing game. I want the AI to select a random letter from this list. I'm doing it as a set so I can easily remove letters from the list as they are guessed in the game and are therefore no longer available to be guessed again.

it says `set` object isn't indexable. How can I work around this?

```
import random

aiTurn = True
while aiTurn == True:
    allLetters = set(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
    aiGuess = random.choice(allLetters)
    print(aiGuess)
```

Comment: Incidentally you don't need to use set(list('string')) to get a set of letters since strings are iterable by themselves -- set('abc') will do what you want.

Comment: For others encountering this problem, it's worth looking at this question about how to create a set-like object which allows efficient random selection.  The options given here are all O(N).  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15993447/2966723

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**Note (Oct. 2020):** as of v3.9, Python has [officially deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.sample) `random.sample()` working on sets, with the official guidance being to explicitly convert the set to a list or tuple before passing it in, though this doesn't solve the efficiency problems.

---

```
>>> random.sample(set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 1)
['f']
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Note that choosing random elements from a set is **extremely inefficient** no matter how you do it - it takes time proportional to the size of the set, or worse if the set's underlying hash table is sparse due to removed elements.

Instead, you should probably use a [different data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993447/python-data-structure-for-efficient-add-remove-and-random-choice) that supports this operation efficiently.

Comment: Tack on a `[0]` at the end so it's basically identical to `random.choice` (which doesn't return it's values in the form of a list)

Comment: `random.sample` does `tuple(population)` internally, so `random.choice(tuple(allLetters))` may be better.

Comment: It should be highlighted that this process is O(N).

Comment: @Joel Why is this process is O(N)?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r 2 reasons.  1) `random.sample` converts the set into a list or tuple and then randomly selects an element from it, so to convert a set to a list takes O(N) operations. This occurs any time you call it with a set.   2) in this particular case, since this starts from a string, converting it to a set also takes O(N).

Comment: I think it's really inefficient... As you can see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/random.py#L332-L339 the sample function creates a list from the set every time you make the above call and takes a random element from it. Suppose you have a large set and you want to make a lot of samples. If the set doesn't change it's better to convert it to a list and use `random.choice`. If the set also changes while you sample it then probably you shouldn't use a set at all. If you would know the occupied hashes in the set and the bucket sizes it would be easy to write a sampling function...

Comment: Note that as of 3.9 Python has [officially deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.sample) `random.sample()` working on sets, with the official guidance being to explicitly convert the set to a list or tuple before passing it in.

Comment: Sampling from a set is not "inefficient no matter how you do it". Python sets use linear probing, so you can simply repeatedly pick random positions in the array until you find one that is set. This completes in expected constant time.

Comment: [This issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue40325) led to the mentioned deprecation, if you're interested in details.

Answer (score 78):

You should use `random.choice(tuple(myset))`, because it's faster and arguably cleaner looking than `random.sample`.  I wrote the following to test:

```
import random
import timeit

bigset = set(random.uniform(0,10000) for x in range(10000))

def choose():
    random.choice(tuple(bigset))

def sample():
    random.sample(bigset,1)[0]

print("random.choice:", timeit.timeit(choose, setup="global bigset", number=10000)) # 1.1082136780023575
print("random.sample:", timeit.timeit(sample, setup="global bigset", number=10000)) # 1.1889629259821959
```

From the numbers it seems that `random.sample` takes 7% longer.

Comment: On my machine, random.choice is 7 times faster.

Comment: There's no way to select directly from set, without having to copy it into tuple?

Comment: I get sample being roughly 12% (250 ms) slower than choose on a set of 5000 elements.

Comment: On my machine, `random.sample` goes from being slower than `random.choice` to being faster than it as the set size grows (the crossover point is somewhere between set size 100k-500k). That is, the larger the set, the more likely it is for `random.sample` to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since the choice list is not very long, you can use random.shuffle the list first. Then iterate each element from the list. This avoid removing element from a list one by one and make your code cleaner.

Comment: damn, this is pretty smart

Comment: but then you can't get same element twice(in general, not in context OP's question)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the set is coming from a string, so you can use the string for the random choice instead.

```
LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

allLetters = set(LETTERS)
aiGuess = random.choice(LETTERS)
print(aiGuess)
```

(This also avoids a [magic constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants).)

---

In my case, I had the same problem with a similar solution. I'm reading words from a file, and I want to pick a random choice as well as put the words into a set in order to get fast membership checks. What ended up being simplest was reading it into a list, then making the choice, converting the list to a set, and deleting the list (implicitly since this is in a function).

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this by using a `list` instead of a `set`. You will still be able to remove letters "easily" from the list. Try this, for example:

```
allLetters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
aiGuess = random.choice(allLetters)
allLetters.remove(aiGuess)
```

Another option is to randomly choose the index instead of the letter, which might be slightly faster since we don't need to search for the element to delete (but I'd question if speed actually matters here?):

```
allLetters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
index = random.randint(0, len(allLetters)-1) # Top is inclusive, unlike slices
aiGuess = allLetters[index]
del allLetters[index]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine a doubly-linked list and a dictionary, to create a set with O(1) random choice.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to get a random element from the set.

```
a = set()
for i in range(10):
    a.add(i)
a.pop() // gives a random element from a set
```

Comment: You need to add it back tho,  `sample = a.pop()` then `a.add(sample)`

Comment: This does not give random element from the set.

Comment: Yes it does. From the API: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html#c.PySet_Pop 

"Return a new reference to an arbitrary object in the set, and removes the object from the set. Return NULL on failure. Raise KeyError if the set is empty. Raise a SystemError if set is not an instance of set or its subtype." 

I'm assuming your beef is that there's no guarantees of pseudo-indeterminism, which you should specify. It's a perfectly good API method that will fulfill "random" requirement for various usecases.

Comment: @user3724404 You cannot assume 'arbitrary' as 'random'. In earlier version of python, the order of pop is definite, in recent python version, the set object(also for dict) is insertion ordered. in both case, the result of pop is predictable, thus not random. I can be 100% sure the popped element in your answer is 0.