# Get random number from set deprecation

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, set, tuples

I am trying to get a random n number of users from a set of unique users.

Here is what I have so far

```
users = set()

random_users = random.sample((users), num_of_user)
```

This works well but it is giving me a deprecated warning. What should I be using instead? random.choice doesn't work with sets

**UPDATE**

I am trying to get reactions on a post and want them to be unique which is why I used a `set`. Would it be better to stick with a list for this?

```
users = set()
    for reaction in msg.reactions:
        async for user in reaction.users():
            users.add(user)
```

Comment: What about, random.choice(list(users), num_of_user)?

Comment: What deprecation warning do you get? Usually deprecation warnings give you an alternative

Comment: What message do you get exactly? As a workaround you could convert your set into a list and pass this list to `.sample()`.

Comment: Sampling from a set deprecated
since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version. @albert

Comment: @PranavHosangadi please see above message

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given @BennyElgazar

Comment: Please see the docs for [`.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and [`.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) for further details and how these functions differ.

Comment: Can you turn your set into a list? `random_users = random.choices([*users],k=num_of_user)`

Comment: @DanielTuzes that worked. Would it be better to start with a list instead of a set? or its the best approach to convert it to a list later? Please see update in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert your set to a list.

1. by using the `list` function:

   ```py
   random_users = random.choices(list(users),k=num_of_user)
   ```
2. by using `*` operator to [unpack your set or dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

   ```py
   random_users = random.choices([*users],k=num_of_user)
   ```

Solution 1. is 3 char longer than the 2., but solution 1. is more literal - to me.

It is not guaranteed that you will get the same result for the list order through different executions, python versions and platforms, therefore you may end up with different random result, despite a careful random number generator initialization. To resolve this issue, order your list.

You can also store the users in a list, and make the elements unique later with set, and then convert again to a list. For this, a [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) is to convert your list to a set, and back to a list again.

Comment: Why not just `list(users)`?

Comment: len("[*users]") < len("list(users)"), however, I'd prefer `list`, it seems easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, `random.sample()` in Python 3.9.2 says this when passed a `dict`:

```
TypeError: Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).
```

And this solution does seem to work for both `set` and `dict` inputs.

Comment: Why would you sort it when you're getting a random value?