# Pick non-repeating random number from progressive list

Tags: java

Here is my example - pick random number from 1-20, then from 2-21, 3-22 and so on, while 
excluding previous picks. I am new to Java, and doing something wrong.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RandomGenerator {

      static int temp;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> randomNumberArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++)
    {
        temp = RandomNumber.nextInt(i+20) +1+i;
        if (!randomNumberArray.contains(temp))
        {
            {
                randomNumberArray.add(temp);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(randomNumberArray);
    }
```

Comment: How does it actually behave, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: You have to repeat nextInt until the condition is met...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to go over.

1) If your number sees that there is a duplicate then it will skip it and continue with the next number, for example if you run it 5 times and it finds a duplicate once, then the resulting list of numbers will have only 4 numbers **not 5!** since it skipped one. (Not sure if this is what you wanted or not)

2) Your randomly generated number doesn't grow the way you expect it to grow.
For example: At the sixth iteration over the loop your random number will generate as:

```
RandomNumber.nextInt(25) +6;
```

That means that the number range there isn't 6-26 but **6-30!**

Because: `nextInt` will return an int between 0 and 24 and then that int is added another 6 to it.

**EDIT :**

To tackle your first problem you can continue to generate numbers until you generate one that is not a duplicate for that single cycle of the for loop.

For this you can utilize the **do-while** loop so that it executes the number generation at least once before checking whether the number is a duplicate within the for loop.

So you can adjust your for loop **from:**

```
for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++)
{
    temp = RandomNumber.nextInt(20) +1+i;
    if (!randomNumberArray.contains(temp))
    {
        {
            randomNumberArray.add(temp);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(randomNumberArray);
}
```

**into:**

```
for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++)
{
    do {
        temp = RandomNumber.nextInt(20) +1+i;
    } while (randomNumberArray.contains(temp));

    randomNumberArray.add(temp);

    System.out.println(randomNumberArray);
}
```

Notice that the check in the while expression is the **opposite** (does not have the exclamation mark) of what was in the if expression in the for loop before, since we `do` want to continue generating new random numbers `while` our numbers are duplicates.

And since we are still looping within that one cycle of the `for` loop, it will always generate the number with the appropriate value of `i` which was set for that for cycle.

Comment: You are correct, making the change to nextInt(20), I get a much better result.  I am still stuck, however, on how to try for a new random number (if there is a repeat) before advancing i. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user184662 you can use a **do-while** loop inside the **for** loop, see the edits I made to my post for details regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't excluding previous picks. Something like this will print twenty random numbers (e.g. all random numbers from 1-20).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.util.Set<Integer> picked = new TreeSet<Integer>();
  Random rand = new Random();
  while (picked.size() < 20) {
    int temp = 1+rand.nextInt(20);
    if (picked.contains(temp)) {
      continue;
    }
    picked.add(temp);
    System.out.println(temp);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure I understand your "stepping" idea, but add this for `temp` and it will do that too -

```
int temp = 1+picked.size()+rand.nextInt(20+picked.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use [Collections.shuffle(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29):

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(list);
```

The progressive version goes something like this:

```
    // Wrap it in an ArrayList so I can modify it.
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
    for (int i = 21; i < 25; i++) {
        System.out.println(list);
        // Shuffle it.
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        // Grab one.
        Integer take = list.get(0);
        list.remove(take);
        System.out.println("Took " + take);
        // Add my new candidate.
        list.add(i);
    }
```

Or you could go the whole hog and make it an `Iterable`:

```
public static class CreepingRandom implements Iterable<Integer> {

    // The starting list.
    private final List<Integer> start;
    // How many steps to add.
    private final int steps;
    // What int to start adding.
    private final int from;

    public CreepingRandom(int initialSize, int from, int steps) {
        // Make my start list.
        start = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialSize);
        // Fill it.
        for (int i = 1; i <= initialSize; i++) {
            start.add(i);
        }
        // Remember where to start from.
        this.from = from;
        // Remember how many steps.
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new CreepingIterator();
    }

    private class CreepingIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

        // Track how many I've delivered.
        int delivered = 0;
        // The next number to add.
        int add = from;
        // My current list.
        final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(start);

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return delivered < steps;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            // Shuffle it.
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            // Pull one out.
            Integer next = list.get(0);
            // Add my new one in.
            list.set(0, add++);
            // Count them.
            delivered += 1;
            return next;
        }

    }

}

public void test() {
    for (Integer i : new CreepingRandom(20, 21, 100)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

    private class CreepingIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

        // Track how many I've delivered.
        int delivered = 0;
        // The next number to add.
        int add = from;
        // My current list.
        final ArrayList<Integer> list;

        CreepingIterator() {
            // Copy the start list - Use LinkedList for efficiency of add and removeFirst.
            list = new ArrayList(start);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return delivered < steps;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            // Shuffle it.
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            // Pull one out.
            Integer next = list.get(0);
            // Add my new one in.
            list.set(0, add++);
            // Count them.
            delivered += 1;
            return next;
        }

    }

}

public void test() {
    for (Integer i : new CreepingRandom(20, 21, 100)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work as the OP expects, the probabilities are different. For example, 21 can't be at the first place in case of polling two elements.

Comment: @Danstahr - printed `[16, 5, 18, 11, 12, 14, 6, 0, 2, 19, 8, 3, 13, 7, 15, 4, 20, 17, 9, 10, 1]` for me - is that not right?

Comment: Oh wait! The range increases! OOps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of allowed elements isn't too big, you can also hold the pool of all possible numbers and pick one of them. You can use e.g. RandomSet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669034/1654825).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    static class RandomSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

        List<E> dta = new ArrayList<E>();
        Map<E, Integer> idx = new HashMap<E, Integer>();

        public RandomSet() {
        }

        public RandomSet(Collection<E> items) {
            for (E item : items) {
                idx.put(item, dta.size());
                dta.add(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(E item) {
            if (idx.containsKey(item)) {
                return false;
            }
            idx.put(item, dta.size());
            dta.add(item);
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Override element at position <code>id</code> with last element.
         * @param id
         */
        public E removeAt(int id) {
            if (id >= dta.size()) {
                return null;
            }
            E res = dta.get(id);
            idx.remove(res);
            E last = dta.remove(dta.size() - 1);
            // skip filling the hole if last is removed
            if (id < dta.size()) {
                idx.put(last, id);
                dta.set(id, last);
            }
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object item) {
            @SuppressWarnings(value = "element-type-mismatch")
            Integer id = idx.get(item);
            if (id == null) {
                return false;
            }
            removeAt(id);
            return true;
        }

        public E get(int i) {
            return dta.get(i);
        }

        public E pollRandom(Random rnd) {
            if (dta.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            int id = rnd.nextInt(dta.size());
            return removeAt(id);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return dta.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return dta.iterator();
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        RandomSet<Integer> rs = new RandomSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            rs.add(i);
        }

        int count = 50;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(rs.pollRandom(r));
            rs.remove(i);
            rs.add(i + 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the smart structure the overall time complexity is `O(N + K)`, where `N` is the number of requested polls and `K` is the size of the pool.

Running Ideone example : http://ideone.com/Sfltr7