# Guava - how can I generate a random number using Range?

Tags: java, random, guava

Google's Guava library provides a great class called [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html), it has many useful methods like `greaterThan(x)`, `open(x,y)`, etc. I am wondering if there is any way of applying such method to generate a random number within a `Range`?

Comment: I see no such method on http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html. What have you tried?

Comment: What's wrong with `Random.nextXXX`?

Comment: No, there's not really a way to do this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider nothing, but you may already have a `Range` object and want a value from within that range. Extracting a random value isn't complicated, but it isn't totally obvious.

Answer (score 7):

I would not suggest using a range for this basic application.

The easiest method to use is the already implemented Random class.

Here is how to use the class:

For getting a random integer of any value:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt();
```

For getting a random integer in a range of min x, max y:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(y - x) + x;
```

This is the most basic way of getting a random number in a range.
I bet there is a getMin and getMax method in the range class, so use that for x and y.

Also, if you want a random number greater than a min value of x, just do:

```
Random r = new Random();
Math.abs(r.nextInt().nextInt()) + x;
```

^The code above generates any positive integer, and the x ensures the min value.

-or-

```
nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE - (x + 1)) + (x + 1)
```

-as suggested by ColinD
Hope this helps.
-Classic

Comment: `new Random().nextInt() + x` won't do what you describe, since `nextInt()` can return any `int` value including negative values and values that are greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE - x`. I think you'd need `nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE - (x + 1)) + (x + 1)` if you want the value to be strictly _greater than_ `x`.

Comment: Using `new Random()` just once is wrong (too inefficient and badly distributed). Even in an example, please write just `random.nextInt()`. And ColinD is right, so please fix this, too.

Comment: Slight correction: the result of `Math.abs(r.nextInt())` can actually be negative if the RNG happens to produce `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Louis says there's no built-in way to do this, but there are a couple of fairly straightforward options. Note that we have to assume all `Range` instances are bounded on both sides - you cannot select a random value from an unbounded or non-discrete range (e.g. `(-∞..0]`).

The easiest to implement solution is to simply convert the `Range` into a [`ContiguousSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ContiguousSet.html), from which you can [select a random value in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124671/113632). This has the advantage of working for any discrete type, not just `Range<Integer>`.

```
public static C random(Range<C> range, DiscreteDomain<C> domain) {
  Set<C> set = ContiguousSet.create(range, domain);
  int index = random.nextInt(set.size());
  return Iterables.get(set, index);
}
```

Of course constant time would be better, especially for large ranges. [Canonicalizing](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#canonical%28com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain%29) the `Range` first reduces the number of cases we have to handle, and we can use the `f(y-x) + x` pattern JClassic suggests.

```
public static int random(Range<Integer> range) {
  checkArgument(range.hasLowerBound() && range.hasUpperBound(),
      "Cannot select a random element from unbounded range %s", range);
  Range<Integer> canonical = range.canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers());
  return random.nextInt(canonical.upperEndpoint() - canonical.lowerEndpoint())
      + canonical.lowerEndpoint();
}
```

You can extend this easily for `Long` with `Random.nextLong()` (but note that `Random.nextLong()` cannot return all `long` values, so `SecureRandom` would be preferable).