# Random generation in Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, random

Is there a method like the `rng.randint()` in the code below for Java?

Are Math.random() o java.util.Random viable for this aim?

```
  ...  

  rng.seed(random_seed)

  child1, child2 = parents

  const1 = child1.const_set
  const2 = child2.const_set

  cp1 = rng.randint(1, len(const1) - 1) if len(const1) > 1 else 0
  cp2 = rng.randint(1, len(const2) - 1) if len(const2) > 1 else 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36918537/8389458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Random().nextInt(<specify bound here>)`

If bound is 5, it will give you a random int less than 5