# How can I program multistage random in Java or Android?

Tags: java, android, random

How can I program multistage random?

An example: I have 3 int: "1;2;3"
After the first round there are only 2 left. For example: "2;3"
And in the last round remain number "3".
All this happened randomly.

How can I program this in Java?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yes but I am beginner :/ and I dont find this in the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an `ArrayList` or `Set` of the `int`. Use `Random.nextInt()` to get a random index that is less than the size of the collection and then access it and remove it. This way no two numbers will repeat.You can use this for `int` or anything you want. Another idea is to use `Collections.shuffle`.

More info: [Picking a random element from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set)

Comment: If the removal should continue until no elements are left, I'd say `Collections.shuffle` is an excellent approach.

Comment: Thank you. with Collections.shuffle it works great ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to store the integers in an array. You can then remove the numbers using a random integer as index for the array. Example:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int numOfInputs = 3;
int[] listOfNums = new int[]{1,2,3};
int removeIndex = 0;

for(int r = 0; r < numOfInputs; r++) {

  removeIndex = rnd.nextInt(numOfInputs);
  listOfNums[removeIndex] = 0;

  // Print the list
  for(int p = 0; p < numOfInputs; p++) {
    if(listOfNums[p] > 0) {
      System.out.print(listOfNums[p] + ";");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you. but how can I write the 3 results into 3 strings or int?