# How to pick two random items from a set?

Tags: java

Given a set X, using java how do I pick two random items from it so that i could maybe increment one item and decrement the other at the same time.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the following link help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the size of the set, and then randomly choose two "indexes" below it. Not that `Set` elements in java don't have real indexes, of course (at least not in the sense that `List`s have them, with a `get(int)` method, but this behavior can be simulated by iterating over the `Set` and counting the number of steps):

```
Set<Object> set = ...;
Random random = new Random(); // or some better RNG
int size = set.size();
int step1 = rand.nextInt(size - 1);
int step2 = rand.mextInt(size - step1);

Iterator<Object> iter = set.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < step1 - 1; ++i) {
    iter.next();
}
Object rand1 = iter.next();

for (int i = 0; i < step2 - 1; ++i) {
    iter.next(); // Note, this is the SAME iterator!
}
Object rand2 = iter.next();
```

Comment: yes this, totally fits my situation