# Returning random key from HashMap

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I  have the following class **Room** and the enum class **Direction**, how would I write a method to pick a random key from the HashMap **exits** and return it, or return `null` if there are no exits in that Room?

```
public class Room 
{
private String description;
private HashMap<Direction, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
public Set<Character> chars;  // stores the characters that are in this room.

/**
 * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
 * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
 * "an open court yard".
 * @param description The room's description.
 * Pre-condition: description is not null.
 */
public Room(String description) 
{
    assert description != null : "Room.Room has null description";
    this.description = description;
    exits = new HashMap<Direction, Room>();
    chars = new HashSet<Character>();
    sane();
}
/**
 * Define an exit from this room.
 * @param direction The direction of the exit.
 * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
 * Pre-condition: neither direction nor neighbor are null; 
 * there is no room in given direction yet.
 */
public void setExit(Direction direction, Room neighbor) 
{
    assert direction != null : "Room.setExit gets null direction";
    assert neighbor != null : "Room.setExit gets null neighbor";
    assert getExit(direction) == null : "Room.setExit set for direction that has neighbor";
    sane();
    exits.put(direction, neighbor);
    sane();
    assert getExit(direction) == neighbor : "Room.setExit has wrong neighbor";
}
```

Direction:

```
public enum Direction
{
NORTH("north"), WEST("west"), SOUTH("south"), EAST("east");

private String name;

/**
 * Constructor with parameter.
 * Pre-condition: name is not null.
 */
private Direction(String name)
{
    assert name != null : "Direction.Direction has null name";
    this.name = name;
    assert toString().equals(name) : "Direction.Direction produces wrong toString";
}

/**
 * Return the direction name.
 */
public String toString()
{
    return name;
}
```

}

Comment: From `exits.keySet()`, grab the `Set<Direction>` and its size, then [pick a random element from the set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set).

Comment: @rgettman how do you mean grab the Set<Direction>?

Comment: @super95 exits.keySet() will return Set<Direction>. Before performing exits.keySet() check if exits in not null. Then follow as rgettman suggested.

Comment: @KaranKhanna I tried that and i always get `null`

Answer (score 0):

**Note :**
As your Map Key is enum Direction, You should always get the value using the same Key type Direction, Otherwise it will return null

Example: `map.get(Direction.NORTH);`

**Solution**

```
 Step 1: Set<Direction> directions=exits.keySet(); 
 Step 2: if(directions.keySet().size()==0){return null;} //check if there is no exit 
 Step 2: Object[] dirArray = directions.toArray();
 Step 3: Random random = new Random();
         int randIndex = random.nextInt(dirArray.length-1);
 Step 4: System.out.println(dirArray [randIndex ]); // Random Direction Here
```

Let me know if you have any doubt, I have tested above code snippet

Answer (score -2):

Something like that:

```
private Direction getRandomDirection() {
    if (exits.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(exits.keySet().size());
    return new ArrayList<>(exits.keySet()).get(rnd);
}
```