# How to pull random string from a keySet?

Tags: java, random, set, keyset

I'm working on a problem in which I need to pull a random String from a keySet. Just wondering if anyone can give me some direction here. I'm pretty lost on it. I've found quite a few ways to do it if I were using an int, but not a String. For example I want to quiz a user on States and their Capitals, and to pull out a random Key from the keySet for the question.
Here's the set:

```
Set<String> states = stateCapitals.keySet();
```

Comment: You can't do random indexing on a Set, but you could use `toArray()` (or `new ArrayList()`) to get a list.  If the set is very large this may be inefficient though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Picking a random element from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124671/picking-a-random-element-from-a-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set` is not the best data structure for random indexing.

Better convert to a `List` and use a random generator to select an `index`. If you really need to stay with a `Set`, you can generate a random index `n` and iterate through the `Set`, stop at the `nth element`. For selecting multiple elements, there is no benefit of working with a `List`. Any `iterable` would be fine.

The key idea is to dynamically adjust selection probability so you can choose m (out of sizeof(Set)): In the easiest example of `m=1`, select 1st element with probability of `1/N`, if you didn't select it, select `2nd element` with probability `1/(N-1)`..and so on.

Use conditional probability to show all elements are selected under a fair chance `1/N`.

Answer (score 1):

A keySet similar to HashSet is un-ordered and thus makes no guarantee to the order of the element in the set. So pulling a random string might not be as effective thing to do from a set.

Convert the set into arrays or list and then performing random string gets might be good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<States> statesList = new ArrayList<>( states );
State x = statesList.get( (int)(statesList.size() * Math.random()) );
```

The code above will get what you want but this could be inefficient if it's a very large list.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ranKey = map.keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(map.keySet().size())].toString();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
onPress: function () {
        debugger;
        var textArray = ['Pritesh', 'Nimesh', 'Harshil', 'Ravi', 'Amit', 'Brijesh'];
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
            if (i === randomNumber) {
                console.log(textArray[i]);
            }
        }
```